# Off-diagonal elements of density matrix in three-level system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, coherent-states

given is a three-level system, let's say an atom with three possible states 1 being the lowest and 3 the highest ($E_1<E_2<E_3$), where
$$
\Psi(t)= C_1(t)|1\rangle+C_2(t)|2\rangle+C_3(t)|3\rangle
$$
is it's wavefunction. The density matrix elements are
$$
\rho_{ij}=C_iC_j^*
$$
$|C_i|^2=\rho_{ii}$ is the probability of the atom being in state $i$. The system gets stimulated by a monochromatic wave with frequency $\omega$. This causes the diagonal elements to oscilate in time (Rabi frequencies).But in my numerical simulation the off diagonal elements also oscilate in time.Can also some physical knowledge be extracted from that? In the internet was often times coherence mentioned. But after reading a little about coherence in quantum mechanics (a coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$ is defined to as $\hat{a}|\alpha\rangle=\alpha|\alpha\rangle$ where $\hat{a}$ is the annihilation operator) I wasnt any smarter. I hope someone knows a little more about the physical meaning of the off diagonal states in this system.